# How to plot 3d scatter of population density in many countries over the years?

Tags: python, plot, dataset, mplot3d, scatter3d

I have data set with 160 countries and the population density in each country over a period of 12 years. I want to plot it in 3D scatter but I get this error:

- ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

I have created three lists - for "year", "country name", "population density"
but it seems I cannot get it right.
This is a sample of the data set:

[image]

This is my code:

```py
g1 = population_density["year"]
g2 = population_density["country_name"]
g3 = population_density["population_density_(people per sq. km of land area)"]

data = (g1, g2, g3)
colors= list(np.random.choice(range(256), size=160))
groups = ("year", "population density per sq.km", "countries") 

# Create plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,8))
#ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
#ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

for data, color, group in zip(data, colors, groups):
    x, y, z = data
    ax.scatter(x, y, z, alpha=0.8, c=color, edgecolors='none', s=30, label=group)

plt.title('Population Density Over The Years')
plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.show()
```

In the end, I want to have the scatter plots for all years this 3d plot. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ax.scatter(x, y, z, alpha=0.8, c=color, edgecolors='none', s=30, label=group)` replace it with `ax.scatter(g1, g2, g3, alpha=0.8, c=color, edgecolors='none', s=30, label=group)`

You should replace x with g1, y with g2 and z with g3. According to the documentation in [matplotlib scatter 3d](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html), the arguments taken in can be in array form. By using a `for` loop you are unpacking the values in the list.

(**Edit**)
After looking at your dataset, you have categorical values in your x and y axis, however scatter plot in 3d requires you to define the cartesian coordinates.
Hence what you can do is to set the `xticks` and `yticks`.

You can possibly do that by this code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

g1 = population_density["year"]
g2 = population_density["country_name"]
g3 = population_density["population_density_(people per sq. km of land area)"]

data = (g1, g2, g3)
colors= list(np.random.choice(range(256), size=len(g1)))

ax.scatter(g1, range(len(g2)), g3, alpha=0.8, c=colors, edgecolors='none', s=30)

ax.set(xticks=range(len(g1)), xticklabels=g1,
       yticks=range(len(g2)), yticklabels=g2,
       zticks=range(len(g3)), zticklabels=g3)

ax.set_xlabel('year')
ax.set_ylabel('countries')
ax.set_zlabel('population density per sq.km')

plt.title('Population Density Over The Years')
plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I got new mistake now: IndexError: tuple index out of range:
```python
for color, group in zip(colors, groups):
    ax.scatter(g1, g2, g3, alpha=0.8, c=color, edgecolors='none', s=30, label=group)
```

Comment: @Yana Please try out the code, I've updated my answer, if you have anymore questions please ask

Comment: This will be difficult :) I got new mistake now: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Afghanistan'
Is it possible that I didn't set the axis lists correctly?

Comment: @Yana you probably have to include a brief snippet of your data set to let us know what we are dealing with.

Comment: @Yana you are passing through categorical values (non-integer values) hence you can solve that by using `xticks` and `yticks` to label on the axis of the countries accordingly.

Comment: I wrote the edited code, but the information is a lot and it does not look good at all.. Thank you.

Comment: @Yana Of course! From your picture im guessing you have thousands of rows of data, which when added to the axis will definitely make it extremely messy. Hence one suggestion is to set different colours for different countries, it will make it much neater. Please feel free to accept this as an answer if you think I've answered your question posted.